# eslint-plugin-import tsconfig aliasing for JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint-plugin-import, eslint-import-resolver-typescript

The [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import?tab=readme-ov-file#typescript) and [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-import-resolver-typescript) docs are quite clear that the latter is needed to support tsconfig @-rules (`compilerOptions.path`).

I have set it up correctly, with these:

```
settings: {
    "import/parsers": {
       "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
       typescript: {
         project,
       },
    }
}
```

Where project is resolved as such:

```
const project = resolve(process.cwd(), "tsconfig.json");
```

I know that works, it comes from [turborepo's examples](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/blob/main/examples/kitchen-sink/packages/config-eslint/next.js).

The issue is when I use JavaScript files (as opposed to TypeScript). `import/no-unresolved` then throws an error.

Any way to fix this. Ideally, the typescript resolver should also be applied to the JavaScript files.